# How to implement drop-down list in table cell

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-spinner, dropdownbox

A table was created to display certain important datas while giving users limited editing functionality. The limited functionality would include a drop down list that lets user choose the following options in that column. However, i have no idea how is it implemented, Any suggestions?

Code written for the creation of the table column:

```
TextView label_Col_5_data = new TextView(this);
label_Col_5_data.setId(200+Count);
label_Col_5_data.setPadding(30, 5, 30, 5);
label_Col_5_data.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

tr.addView(label_Col_5_data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add one on click listener like this.

```
label_Col_5_data.setOnClickListener(operationListener );

OnClickListener operationListener = new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            int _clickId = v.getId();
            // Write your popup code here.

        }
    };
```

Comment: operation listener cannot be resolved into a variable while onclicklistener cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: implement your class using onClickListener

Answer (score 1):

Just use below code and create your dialog.

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Info", "Rename", "Delete"};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(write your activity context);
    builder.setTitle("Options for " + file.getName());
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            //Set data here
        }
    }).show();
```